# Regex equal to or high than 125233000

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need a regex (for Google Analytics) that matches this number and any numbers higher: 125,233,000.

My regex skills are non-existent so big thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: That’s not really what regex is for. You should post your actual problem and ask for solutions, rather than assuming a regular expression is the right way to accomplish whatever you’re trying to do here.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for Google Analytics and they offer no other options for filtering for pages in such a way, but only very simple checks for whether a specific string is included. But your point is taken. I'm new here so not aware yet if there is a Google Analytics specific topic. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression feels like the wrong way to to this, but something like this might work:

```
12523[3-9]\d{3}|1252[4-9]\d{4}|125[3-9]\d{5}|12[6-9]\d{6}|1[3-9]\d{7}|[2-9]\d{8}|\d{10,}
```

Here is a visualization of what this pattern is doing: [Regexper](https://regexper.com/#12523%5B3-9%5D%5Cd%7B3%7D%7C1252%5B4-9%5D%5Cd%7B4%7D%7C125%5B3-9%5D%5Cd%7B5%7D%7C12%5B6-9%5D%5Cd%7B6%7D%7C1%5B3-9%5D%5Cd%7B7%7D%7C%5B2-9%5D%5Cd%7B8%7D%7C%5Cd%7B10%2C%7D%0A)

The overall expression is made up of several smaller expressions that all follow the same general structure, separated by the `|` (the equivalent of "or"). Here's one as an example:

```
1252[4-9]\d{4}
```

Breaking this expression down:

- `1252` - match the string `1252` exactly
- `[4-9]` - match `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, or `9`
- `\d{4}` - match any 4 numbers (0-9)

The final part of the overall pattern is `\d{9,}`, which matches any sequence of at least 9 numbers.

Comment: The second alternative should be `1252[4-9]\d{4}`, as handling `12523` is covered in your first - and so on. I wouldn't recommend using `\d{9}` if leading zeros are a thing.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Also, that Regexper link is very cool. It might be first time I looked at something and felt like I understood what the regex was actually doing.

Comment: @SebastianProske - you might be right, just put this together quickly - thanks for taking the time to double check my work :)

Comment: @C.Haley Can't recommend Regexper enough - I show it to everyone who has to do any work with regular expressions, it's great to be able to change a few characters and then see a visual representation of how the pattern changes.

Comment: @Donut well at the moment it allows a couple of false positives, e.g. `[1-9]\d{8}` will match `100000000` which is less than `125232000`